# Plugin builder - how to validate input values from a plugin dialog

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I have a question regarding adding a warning popup when a user pressed OK while forgetting to fill in all the required fields in the plugin dialog. 
I have the following definition which checks if all fields contain text:

```
def inputCheck(self):
    if self.dlg.lineEdit_dxf.text() == "":
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Warning!", "Select a .dxf file" )
        return False
    return True
```

I thought that by adding the following code (see below) in the "def run(self)" part of the script the dialog would not close when the user presses OK. However, while the popup works fine and the script does not run, the dialog still closes down.

```
def run(self):
    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        if not self.inputCheck():
            return

        #rest of script#
```

I built my plugin with the help of the plugin builder and I have not changed the overall layout of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overwrite the dialog's `accept()` method to be able to validate values **before** the dialog is actually accepted.

Go to the dialog Python file and add an `accept()` method at the end of the file, at the same indentation level as the constructor `__init__( self ):`

```
def accept( self ):
    validInput = self.inputCheck()
    if validInput:
       self.done( 1 ) # Only accept the dialog if all inputs are valid
```

As `accept()` needs to call `inputCheck()`, it makes sense to move your `inputCheck()` function into the dialog Python file. Just keep in mind that you won't need the `self.dlg` object, since you can access the dialog controls directly from the `self` object:

```
def inputCheck(self):
    if self.lineEdit_dxf.text() == "":
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Warning!", "Select a .dxf file" )
        return False
    return True
```

*Note 1: You don't need to modify the original `run()` method in the plugin's main Python file, i.e., leave it as it was when created.*

*Note 2: Instead of showing a modal message box that blocks the entire application, you could show a Message Bar inside your plugin's dialog. See [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html#id1) for details*.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out Germán Carrillo. It works perfectly!

Comment: Hi, How do you implement this with "show a Message Bar inside your plugin's dialog"

Comment: You need to add [these lines](https://github.com/SwissTierrasColombia/Asistente-LADM-COL/blob/master/asistente_ladm_col/gui/dialogs/dlg_import_from_excel.py#L149-L152) to your dialog (normally in the `__init__()` itself) and then show the message in this way: https://github.com/SwissTierrasColombia/Asistente-LADM-COL/blob/master/asistente_ladm_col/gui/dialogs/dlg_import_from_excel.py#L575-L577

Comment: Germán Carrillo, 7 years later you may have saved me big time with this answer